# Initial value problem and characteristic equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have this initial value problem:

$u_t + xu_x = -u^2$, with   $u(x,0)=1$.

So from this we have

$ \dfrac{dt}{1} = \dfrac{dx}{u} = \dfrac{du}{u^2}$

so $\dfrac{du}{dt} = -u^2 \implies u=\dfrac{1}{t+w}$

and $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = u \implies x=tu+z \implies z=x-tu$

where $w$,$z$ are constants. My problem is that I'm not too sure how to illustrate $u(x,t)$ as , since this is implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations are incorrect. Thew equation should be
$$
\dfrac{dt}{1} = \dfrac{dx}{x} = \dfrac{du}{u^2}.
$$
Observe that the equation for $x$ is different. The solution is
$$
x=C\,e^t,\quad u=\frac{1}{t+w}.
$$
From here and the initial condition you find
$$
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{1+t}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for that, I knew I was going wrong somewhere with it being implicit.

Comment: So I end up having $u(x,t) = \dfrac{1}{t+w(z)}$. When I plug in the initial value, I end up with $w(x)=1$. Do I just substitute this back into $u(x,t)$ or into $z=x-\mathrm{log}(t+w)$ seeing as we would have $w(z)$ in $u(x,t)$?

Comment: I have edited my answer, because it was wrong.